# How to configure ListView to automatically change its height?

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I have three `ListView` widgets in the same `LinearLayout`. Something like this (I'm omitting XML elements that are not relevant in this example):

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="360dp"/>
    <ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="360dp"/>
    <ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="360dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This forces the list to have a height of 360 dip. Of course, that will be its height even if there are few list items. So, my question is how can make the lists have an automatic height? What I want is that the `ListView` height takes the exact size of the sum of all its list items.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to make the 3 ListViews inside a LinearLayout like this? Perhaps there is a better approach to your problem. As you might have picked up from the answers, you are gonna have to write some annoyingly detailed code to get this to work properly in all situations. Are you sure you don't just want a LinearLayout with the items directly inside of it? If the ListViews are just so you can use some adapter, could you perhaps merge all the adapter results into one?

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely a UI desing problem there. Though, it's a source code that someone left in a project that I recently took, and the deadline is today. So, what the boss tell me to do was just make it look better, rather than refactoring the whole app. Of course, I will try to fix that in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've implemented it this way (code is work in progress so it's more a idea source than solution):

```
package com.customcontrols;
public class NoScrollListView extends ListView
{
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, 0) );

        // here I assume that height's being calculated for one-child only, seen it in ListView's source which is actually a bad idea
        int childHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - (getListPaddingTop() + getListPaddingBottom() +  getVerticalFadingEdgeLength() * 2);

        int fullHeight = getListPaddingTop() + getListPaddingBottom() + childHeight*(getCount());

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), fullHeight);
    }
}
```

the calculation's not perfect, but it's close and works so far.
after that you just create a layout like this:

ScrollView
   com.customcontrol.NoScrollListView
   com.customcontrol.NoScrollListView
   com.customcontrol.NoScrollListView
/ScrollView

The scrollView's crucial since you can easily run out of screen bounds.

PS. The calculation's rectum-driven since most of the calculation methods in ListView&Co are package private which is quite a strange choice for publicly inheritable classes for UI.

Comment: See below my evolved version that supports differently-height items

Comment: #1 - Don't reference other answers as being "above" or "below". Answers on StackOverflow are often sorted by score, which can change overtime, not time, which is immutable. #2 - Why not just edit your existing answer to contain both your partially implemented and fully implemented code? Either way, thanks for the help :)

Comment: In my comment from 28 Jul 2010 please read "later" instead of "below".

Comment: As for the why two versions - because my first answer was accepted as a solution and if I change the text - different solution will appear as accepted. Theoretically I can replace my answer with quote from Alice In Wonderland. That, imo, can be disastorous.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of editing my previous answer, here's my actual version (after finally the case became the issue and I had to fix it)

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, 0));

    int childHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - (getListPaddingTop() + getListPaddingBottom() +  getVerticalFadingEdgeLength() * 2);

    // on a first run let's have a space for at least one child so it'll trigger remeasurement
    int fullHeight = getListPaddingTop() + getListPaddingBottom() + childHeight*(getCount());

    int newChildHeight = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x<getChildCount(); x++ ){
        View childAt = getChildAt(x);

        if (childAt != null) {
            int height = childAt.getHeight();
            newChildHeight += height;
        }
    }

    //on a second run with actual items - use proper size
    if (newChildHeight != 0)
        fullHeight = getListPaddingTop() + getListPaddingBottom() + newChildHeight;

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), fullHeight);
}
```

The trickiest part is that the onMeasure gets called twice, first for approx layout and then after items added for a precise one and both have to return sane results.

Answer (score 3):

i found a solution on [set ListView Height Based On Children](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm), this work

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this... list view real height

list view xml coding

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/my_listview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

list view java coding

```
    ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lView);
```

setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren method

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Pretty Awesome. For this issue, I have spent so many days. Other codings are so heavy. You crack it pretty good... Thank you so much for the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating over the `ListView`'s rows (see methods on `ViewGroup`), find their heights, sum them, and change your `ListView` height.

That being said, I fully expect this to be awful:

- You need to take into account the screen size, so your lists do not go past the bounds of the screen
- You need to take into account orientation changes
- You need to take into account any modifications to your data (e.g., deleting rows may require your list to shrink)
- Etc.

If your goal really is to have a single list, but you have three sources of data, merge the data and put it into a single list. My [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) can help here.