# How to scroll down to the footer of a list view and show the whole footer

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a long list with a big header and footer and I need to scroll the list all the way down and show the **whole** footer.
Also, items can have very different height so the overall height cannot be simply calculated height * no items.

All the existing questions I've seen do not take in account the footer might be big and not entirely shown when scrolling to last position.

So far I've tried:

1) the simplest solution:

```
lv.setSelection(lv.getCount() - 1);
```

However this will not show the whole footer, only part of it and I need to have it all visible.

2) using:

```
requestFocus();
```

on the footer, the main layout in it, and any elements in the footer: this changes the focus but doesn't force the listview to scroll down.

3) using:

```
lv.scrollTo(x, y);
```

problem with this is that I couldn't get the real height of the listview in a reliable way as items are not fixed size.
Beside, after scrolling often part of the list is not shown leaving a wide white area.

4) header and footer are contained in two adapters but I couldn't figure out how to reach them to be shown on the screen

5) I have also tried a mixed approach:

```
lv.setSelection(lv.getCount() - 1);
lv.scrollListBy(mFooter.getHeight());
```

But the scrollListBy() doesn't seem to have any effects after a setSelection - not sure why.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: lv.scrollTo should do the job, you cant know its content height because its created by xml file right?

Comment: yes the adapter inflates the xml file and its content my expand over several lines so each item height can be anything really

Comment: Still you should be able to do it, you can get each element size after it draws.

Comment: I've tried to, I also tried this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4734708/4559141 but I couldn't get a reliable solution. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't with the same data, so I guess it's some timing issue.